# A potential wrong proof of a Lemma

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider the following lemma: Let $g \in H^s_{x,y}(S)$ where $S = \mathbb{R}^2$ or $S = \mathbb{T}^2$, and $\eta \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $\operatorname{Supp}(\eta) \subset [-2,2]$, and $\eta \equiv 1$ on $[-1,1]$. Then

$$\| \eta(t)e^{tL} g\|_{X^{s,b}} \le C(\eta,b) \|g\|_{H^s_{x,y}}.$$

Where $L$ is a symmetric linear operator of some nonlinear dispersive PDE, and $X^{s,b}$ is the standard Bourgain spaces (Fourier restriction method).

The proof started with this following step:

$$\mathcal{F}[\eta(t) e^{t L}g](\tau,\xi,\mu)= \hat{\eta}(\tau-h(\xi,\mu))\hat{g}(\xi,\mu).$$

where $\mathcal{F}$ is the space-time Fourier transforms, and $h$ is the dispersion relation.

As far as I know, there must be a convolution on the time variable!I believe that this step is a mistake! Am I right? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The shifting of $\hat \eta$ by $h(\xi, \mu) $ is a convolution with the Dirac mass at $h(\xi, \mu) $; this is where the time convolution is "hiding".

Comment: @TerryTao Thanks so much professor